# Windows 8 Metro App's "Can't Open"

Tags: windows-8-preview, modern-ui, windows-store-app

I have installed the Windows 8 consumer preview and all working fine, with the exception of the communication apps (mail, calendar & people).

The apps were working during initial installation process, but at some point ceased to operate. The message I receive when launching is "Mail can't open", "Calendar can't open" and "People can't open". I also note that the Weather app doesn't work, and simply hangs on loading screen.

I have attempted install numerous times, but cannot establish the point at which the apps stop working. I assume it probably relates to one of the updates, but that is only a guess.

Has anyone else experienced this? Does anyone have any ideas on resolution?

Many thanks.

Comment: Betting some service isn't started but I can't think of which one would be the culprit.  Might look in `services.msc` though.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but I resolved it, I found that the antivirus Firewall was the cause, it blocks all metro apps to connect to the network, disable it or change the Firewall rules.

Comment: For me, it was Avast antivirus's real time protection. Solution: http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/37217-Serious-bug-with-Avast-Avant-Internet-Security-with-Metro-Apps-%28Solution-Found%29

Answer (score 1):

Metro apps won't start if the screen resolution is less than 1024x768, is this your case?

It happened to me when I was running Win8 in Virtualbox http://www.dandandin.net/what-to-do-if-windows-8-does-not-run-any-app.aspx

Comment: Screen resolution is well above 1024x768. The issue isn't that nothing happens, or the similarly reported white screen issue. I get a message stating "Mail can't open", for example.

Comment: In that case I never experienced that...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as well (on release preview). A first hint gave the SkyDrive app that failed as well, but mentioning that it failed to login for some reason (0x8009000B). What fixed the issue for me:

- Settings > Change PC Settings > Users > Switch to a local account

Then when starting the calendar, it asked me to sign in and worked fine again. And it still worked after changing the account back to a Microsoft/Live account and verifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Update: SOLVED!

The problem occurs if you tweak your background colors using a tool or manually. Restore all the default registry entries or default colors using the tool and poof! Problem is gone....

Hope this helps, Phew!

---

This's not exactly an answer but I've the very same problem.
And I've been looking for an answer and have tried the following.

1. Uninstall, re-install - doesn't fix.
2. Create new user on Consumer preview and try these apps/ re-install there. - doesn't fix
   so 1 thing is for certain, the problem is not within the "Users or Users/name/appdata"
3. I replace all metro app files in my PC (taking ownership) for another working fresh Consumer Preview install on another PC (where the people/msgs/cal/email app works fine). - Still doesn't fix.
   so the program files ain't the culprit either.
4. That leaves 2 things - the windows folder (the metro framework) and the registry.
   Now the problem can't be with the metro framework because other apps work fine and the msgs/people/mail/cal app can be uninstalled which means it is not coded into the system.

So that leaves the registry, which should be the culprit.  I have yet to try messing with the registry to solve this. Will edit this answer if I do find something.

Refresh apparently solves this but I don't want to be re-installing all my desktop apps.