# Select custom color for metro UI in Win8 CP

Tags: colors, windows-8-preview, modern-ui

I would like to select (really) custom color of metro interface in Windows 8 Consumer Preview. The color set in metro control panel is very limited. [There is a technique](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-change-windows-8-metro-start-menu-background-colors/) which changes color in Developer Preview. Because there's already in CP (very restrictive) way to change this, is there any hack to choose custom color(maybe with registry support)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool out there - http://www.intowindows.com/windows-8-consumer-preview-start-screen-customizer/

But beware, it breaks the mail/messaging/people/calendar app (and some dialogs)
see my answer here - [Windows 8 Metro App's "Can't Open"](https://superuser.com/questions/411523/windows-8-metro-apps-cant-open/419864#419864)

You could ask the author if the latest version or if he's working on another version is this specific-bug-free

Comment: I am sorry, but this tool changed nothing (it didn't even break apps), probably because it only supports Developer Preview.

Comment: sorry edit: I was using this tool - http://www.intowindows.com/windows-8-consumer-preview-start-screen-customizer/ this breaks the apps. I had deleted the tool when I answered this and had used kishan's tool on wdp so got mixed up. Anyway RP is coming in 2 days

Comment: cool. By the way Release Preview up today. Has many more colors (total 25 I guess)

Comment: yup, I am downloading right now.. color schemes there are just great!